# Is defining a default value for a Boolean input property in Angular bad practice?

Tags: angular, variables, properties

I'm looking through an old Angular project and one component has an input property:

```
@Input()
isNotAdmin = true;
```

Is directly assigning a value to the property within it's declaration like this considered bad practice? I understand that it depends on the context e.g. if we would like each of these components to have this property set to true if not stated, but I feel like boolean properties should be explicitly stated either way (true or false). Should the approach instead have a setter method as the input and a check to see if a value is passed, and if not, assign the property a default value?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with initializing a boolean property to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't a bad practice.

In fact, it would even be a best practice.

The reason is that inputs are set only on `ngOnChanges` runs, so that means that until this function is ran, your value is undefined.

For a boolean, it's no big deal. But imagine a complex object, and you do operations on that object, something like

```
if (this.myInput.type.ref.date.modifiedAt.includes('+1'))
```

Then your condition would throw an error.

Moreover, this allows for no-value inputs : imagine you create a custom select, and you want to assign a `multiple` input : what is the best approach for a dev ?

Personnaly, I like the first one. To achieve that, you can use this :

```
@Input('multiple') doNotShowMultipleValues = true;
```

When the dev will use the first syntax, the value will become `''`, which is falsy, thus inverting the condition. Something you can not do without an initial value !

But in the end, it all comes to personal preference, and if you don't feel confident assigning a default value, then you should simply not do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a default value if the input is not bound, what you wrote is a valid approach.

However, if you instead intend to provide a default value if the bound value is `null` or `undefined`, using a setter is the way to go:

```
private _isNotAdmin = true;

@Input()
set isNotAdmin(value: boolean) {
    if (value != null) {
        this._isNotAdmin = value;
    } else {
        this._isNotAdmin = true;
    }
}

get isNotAdmin(): boolean {
    return this._isNotAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is considered a bad practice, Instead you can assign an input to true in ngOnChanges, Check there if changes.isNotAdmin === undefined, then assign it to 'true'.

There you can control any input property and react accordingly